# pgfplots: alignment and size of math in legend

Tags: pgfplots, legend

The legend entries created by a more complex math formula as in this example are overlapping and the alignment to the lines is wrong.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=0.8\textwidth, height=0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,samples=2000,
         /pgfplots/enlargelimits=false,
         legend style={legend pos=north west}]
  \addplot[domain=0:30] gnuplot{5*exp(-((x-5*pi)/(2.5*pi))**2)*sin(2*x)+x};
  \addplot[domain=0:30] gnuplot{x};
  \legend{$f(x) = 5\exp\left(-\left(\dfrac{x-5\pi}{2.5\pi}\right)^2\right)
             \sin(2x) + x$,
          $f(x)_\text{fit} = x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or you can shift the formula slightly with `\legend{{\raisebox{1.5ex}{$f(x) = 5\exp\left(-\left(\dfrac{x-5\pi}{2.5\pi}\right)^2\right)\sin(2x) + x$}},$f(x)_\text{fit} = x$}`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The alignment can be changed using

```
legend cell align=left,
```

The other issues can be changed in a variety of different ways- in what follows I didn't use `samples=2000` as it increases the compiling time quite significantly- the question was independent from this though.

- using `legend style={legend pos=north west,font=\tiny}` gives

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
                    legend cell align=left,
         /pgfplots/enlargelimits=false,
          legend style={legend pos=north west,font=\tiny}]
  \addplot[domain=0:30] {5*exp(-((x-5*pi)/(2.5*pi))^2)*sin(deg(2*x))+x};
  \addplot[domain=0:30] {x};
  \legend{$f(x) = 5\exp\left(-\left(\dfrac{x-5\pi}{2.5\pi}\right)^2\right)
             \sin(2x) + x$,
          $f(x)_\text{fit} = x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

- Using @percusse's `\raisebox` idea (permission to post given during chat- thanks @percusse!)

  ```
  \legend{\raisebox{2.5ex}{$f(x) = 5\exp\left(-\left(\dfrac{x-5\pi}{2.5   \pi}\right)^2\right)\sin(2x) + x$}
  ```

[image]

- Using a blank line in the legend

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
         /pgfplots/enlargelimits=false,
         legend cell align=left,
         legend style={legend pos=north west,font=\tiny}]
  \addplot[domain=0:30] {5*exp(-((x-5*pi)/(2.5*pi))^2)*sin(deg(2*x))+x};
  \addlegendentry{$f(x) = 5\exp\left(-\left(\dfrac{x-5\pi}{2.5\pi}\right)^2\right)$}
  \addlegendimage{empty legend};
  \addlegendentry{};
  \addplot[domain=0:30] {x};
  \addlegendentry{$f(x)_\text{fit} = x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

- Or you could put the legend in the `caption` using `\label` and `\ref`

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis,
                    legend cell align=left,
         /pgfplots/enlargelimits=false,
          legend style={legend pos=north west,font=\tiny}]
  \addplot[domain=0:30] {5*exp(-((x-5*pi)/(2.5*pi))^2)*sin(deg(2*x))+x};
  \label{plot:firstplot};
  \addplot[domain=0:30] {x};
  \label{plot:secondplot};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\ref{plot:firstplot} is $f(x) = 5\exp\left(-\left(\dfrac{x-5\pi}{2.5\pi}\right)^2\right)\sin(2x) + x$ and 
\ref{plot:secondplot} is $f(x)_\text{fit}=x$}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: If you add an example with the raisebox code I could accept your answer. I use now `font=\small`and `\raisebox{2.5ex}{...}`

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech the `\raisebox...` wasn't my idea, it was @percusse's, so I'm not sure if I should make that edit. You could still upvote my answer though :)

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech done